# I am unable to find Database and tables, which I have created in PostgreSQL, Can anyone tell me where those are stored on the hard disk?

Tags: postgresql

I am unable to find database and tables, which I have created in PostgreSQL. Can anyone tell me where those are stored on the hard disk?

Comment: Im not sure why you want disc location. Your tables should be stored in files, that names will not tell you anything. They should be stored somewhere in %postgresInstallFolder%/data/ How you are creating those databases and tables? perhaps there is some error in logs?

Answer (score 1):

You better don't go directly to the file system to investigate databases and tables as you may corrupt your database.

You can list all databases from the command line with the `-l` option

```
psql -l
```

To list all tables, you connect to the database, and execute the command (with `-c`) to describe tables `\dt`

```
psql your_database -c "\dt"
```

Answer (score 0):

The tables are stored in the data directory of the Postgres server. You can get this location by

```
show data_directory;
```

in `psql`.

**But** Postgres stores the data in an internal and very efficient format. So it should be very difficult to read the tables without using the Postgres server.